# Why are "dictionary" and "keys" not defined in python?

Tags: python, json

I'm great with PHP and trying to learn Python. So forgive me if I'm trying to translate functions too literally, but here's what I have:

```
import json
import urllib


url='http://www.example.com/sample.json'
f = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(f.read())


for item in data:
    for entry in item:
        print dictionary.keys(entry)
```

I know that `item` has type dict because I did `print type(item)`. But when I try to run the code above, I get `NameError: name 'dictionary' is not defined` -- do I need to import a library that defines dictionary functions? If so, which library?

Comment: It's just `entry.keys()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Write

```
print entry.keys()
```

instead of

```
print dictionary.keys(entry)
```

I'd recommend having a look at the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and the [library reference](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict).

Comment: actually, it seems I needed `item.keys()`; thanks for the tutorial links. I've been reading a lot of both but hadn't found the tutorial.

Comment: @Amanda: It could well be the case that you need `item.keys()`. It depends on the structure of `data` and things therein.